# Bot not saying welcome when someone joins and bot not sending dm's when I want it to do

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Soo i want my bot to send a message when someone join but it is not workin

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.util.get(member.Guild, name='general')
    await channel.send(f'Hey welcome to my server {member.mention}, hope you enjoy this server!')
```

and
i want my bot to take a massage from me and send it to the guy i say but this is not workin too

```
      
    massage = await client.wait_for('massage', check=check)
    await ctx.send(f'send massage to {member} ')
  
    await member.send(f'{ctx.member.mention} has a massage for you: \n {massage}')
```

and
here is my WHOLE code:

```
import os, discord,asyncio 
import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

token = os.environ.get('Token')
GUILD = os.environ.get('Guild')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} is connected')

@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send('what do u want to say bitch!')
    def check(m):
        return m.author.id == ctx.author.id

      
    massage = await client.wait_for('massage', check=check)
    await ctx.send(f'send massage to {member} ')
  
    await member.send(f'{ctx.member.mention} has a massage for you: \n {massage}')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.util.get(member.Guild, name='general')
    await channel.send(f'Hey welcome to my server {member.mention}, hope you enjoy this server!')
  


      


keep_alive.keep_alive()
client.run(token)
```

Comment: It's a typo. Should be `member.guild` not `member.Guild` uppercase names are for class names by convention.

Comment: Didnt fix the issue still not workin

Comment: It's also `discord.utils` not `util`. It would be great if you read the errors, or at least provide them in the question.

Comment: and you are trying to get a channel it should be `member.guild.text_channels`

Comment: Intents might be needed. You're probably missing `message_content` and `members`.

Comment: i have all there intents!

Answer (score 1):

For making a welcome channel, it is safer to use `get_channel` instead of `get`. Because in your code, every time you rename your channel, you need to change your code too, but channel ids cannot be changed until if you delete and create another one with the same name.

Code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID_GOES_HERE)
    await channel.send(f'Hey welcome to my server {member.mention}, hope you enjoy this server!')
```

As for the `dm` command, I recommend you to get your message as a function parameter. Also you can check when you're DM'ing your bot with the `isinstance()` function. There is a `*` before the `message` parameter though. Its purpose is collecting all of your messages with or without spacing.

Code:

```py
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, member:discord.Member,*, message):
    if isinstance(ctx.channel,discord.DMChannel):
        await member.send(f'{ctx.member.mention} has a message for you: \n {message}')
```

Comment: why is the dm one still not woking
i put 
!dm @myTag Hi
didnt work
why?

and the welcome one is not working too
why is this happening?

Comment: You need to dm your bot to use `!dm` command. You can tag people like this: `<@DISCORD_ID>`.
Also did you correctly placed your channel ID into the brackets?

Comment: Ohhh i got it 
yea i think soo 
i put the numbers in there
that discord copy

Comment: You can test `on_member_join` block with `print(channel)`. Maybe your channel is returning `None` somehow

Comment: and How does !dm works ?
i need to dm it and say !dm <@Herobrinemen#9752> hi  like this
or
Like this !dm @Herobrinemen#9752 Hi

Comment: No, not like that. You need to right click and copy the ID of a user. Let's assume the ID of an user is `1234567890`. Then the correct usage of tagging people with brackets is `<@1234567890>`

Comment: It gives Me an error :/

Comment: it shows nothing in server and in dm give me an error!

Comment: i enabled the 3 intents

Comment: Can you share the error message please?

Comment: it is soo long Soo i put it in paste bin
https://pastebin.com/15rAB2ie
here it is

Comment: @qRnt I would remove the quotes from `get_channel` (even you wrote inside "WITHOUT_QUOTATION_MARKS". Also I would write `discord.DMChannel` instead of `discord.channel.DMChannel`. It makes more sense in the context of the docs.

Comment: Edited like you say, thanks.

Comment: @MrMortal Did you enable your intents? Also I think your bot and the person you want to message needs to be in same server.

Comment: Yes they are in the same servers and i enabled the intents from my dev portal
but i didnt change anything in my code

Comment: Change your code like this and try again. Let me know if there are any problems.
`client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",intents = discord.Intents.all())`